# Launch shell script from another script

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing

I have the following shell script

```
#for i in {0..10}
do
  run my command that takes about 10 seconds with parameter $i
done
```

How can I get this to run the commands in parallel without using GNU Parallel as I am not able to install it on my linux box.

Is there a way I can create 10 different shell scripts and call them e.g. script_1.sh, script_2.sh, script_3.sh etc and then launch them one by one from this script?

Comment: Can you elaborate on if the reason why you cannot install GNU Parallel is covered by http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an ampersand (`&`) and launch `script.sh $1 &` ten times. This will make the script run in a fork of the main process. It is an easy way to do parallel processing but definitely not very flexible and doesn't have many features. A simple tutorial can be found [here](http://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html).